# How to differentiate dates between two days

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to differentiate dates between two dates with different background color, How to do that?
And on hover of any date I want to change the background color of the dates between the selected dates.
My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/t739t99a/ 
I am trying to do something like this http://codepen.io/davidkpiano/full/wBGjMr/

```
.pika-single {
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.pika-single.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.pika-single.is-bound {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.pika-title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.pika-label {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.pika-title select {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9998;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 5px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.pika-prev,
.pika-next {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    /* hide text using text-indent trick, using width value (it's enough) */
    text-indent: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 75% 75%;
    opacity: .5;
    *position: absolute;
    *top: 0;
}

.pika-prev:hover,
.pika-next:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.pika-prev,
.is-rtl .pika-next {
    float: left;
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAUklEQVR42u3VMQoAIBADQf8Pgj+OD9hG2CtONJB2ymQkKe0HbwAP0xucDiQWARITIDEBEnMgMQ8S8+AqBIl6kKgHiXqQqAeJepBo/z38J/U0uAHlaBkBl9I4GwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
    *left: 0;
}

.pika-next,
.is-rtl .pika-prev {
    float: right;
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAU0lEQVR42u3VOwoAMAgE0dwfAnNjU26bYkBCFGwfiL9VVWoO+BJ4Gf3gtsEKKoFBNTCoCAYVwaAiGNQGMUHMkjGbgjk2mIONuXo0nC8XnCf1JXgArVIZAQh5TKYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    *right: 0;
}

.pika-prev.is-disabled,
.pika-next.is-disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: .2;
}

.pika-select {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}

.pika-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.pika-table th,
.pika-table td {
    width: 14.285714285714286%;
    padding: 0;
}

.pika-table th {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.pika-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.25);
}

.is-today .pika-button {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.is-selected .pika-button {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ff4081;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.is-disabled .pika-button {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: #999;
    opacity: .3;
    background: #eee;
}

.pika-button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff4081;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Html code

```
<div class="pika-single is-bound">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pika-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
            <td data-day="1" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">1</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-day="2" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">2</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="3" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">3</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="4" class="is-selected">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">4</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="5" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">5</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="6" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">6</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="7" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">7</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="8" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">8</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-day="9" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">9</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="10" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">10</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="11" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">11</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="12" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">12</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="13" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">13</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="14" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">14</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="15" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">15</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-day="16" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">16</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="17" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">17</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="18" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">18</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="19" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">19</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="20" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">20</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="21" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">21</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="22" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">22</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-day="23" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">23</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="24" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">24</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="25" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">25</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="26" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">26</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="27" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">27</button>
            </td>
            <td data-day="28" class="">
                <button class="pika-button" type="button">28</button>
            </td>
            <td class="is-empty"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `500 - Internal server error.` click on `Run code snippet`

Comment: @Sadikhasan: It's a Stackoverflow Error... (This is the file it is trying to reach: http://stacksnippets.net/js)

Comment: @please find my code here http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/t739t99a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged JQuery, I propose something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/t739t99a/1/ ?

```
$(".pika-button").hover(function() {
  var currentVal = parseInt($(this).parent('td').attr("data-day"));
  var selectedVal = parseInt($(".is-selected").attr("data-day"));

    if (currentVal > selectedVal) {
      var tmp = currentVal;
      currentVal = selectedVal;
      selectedVal = tmp;
    }   
    for (var i=currentVal; i<selectedVal; i++) {
        $("td[data-day='"+i+"']").addClass("between");   
    }
}, function() {
    $(".between").removeClass("between");
});
```

---

```
.between button {
    background-color: #908081;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Davids example he uses inputs because than you can check with css if they are checked or not.
With that you can do quite a log like:

All Days have a white background.

```
.day {
 background: #fff
}
```

The checked days has a darker background.

```
.day:checked {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}
```

All days after the first checked day have a transparent background.

```
.day:checked:nth-child(1) ~ .day {
 background: transparent;
}
```

and all days after the second checked day have a white background again.

```
.day:checked:nth-child(2) ~ .day {
 background: white;
}
```

... i have not tested this code but its pretty simular to what David used in your example.

Comment: Please see my html is it possible do the same in my html template why I am saying is because I am using pickyday plugin in that I can't change the plugin template please try to help me